# Percent Price Change During Rolling Date Range

Tags: pandas, loops, stock, rate

I need to identify instances where the percent change on a per symbol basis exceeds 3% increase over a rolling 1 day date range. The output should include the date range and % increase for each symbol. The sample data includes all applicable fields I think are required to complete. The entire data is about 7 million line items.

Raw data

```
    +--------+-----------+--------+
    | Symbol |   Date    | Price  |
    +--------+-----------+--------+
    | AAPL   | 9/10/2019 | 4.3912 |
    | AAPL   | 4/5/2019  | 3.6599 |
    | AAPL   | 9/10/2019 | 3.5299 |
    | AAPL   | 9/9/2019  | 2.7766 |
    | AAPL   | 9/8/2019  | 2.6845 |
    | AAPL   | 2/2/2019  | 2.6501 |
    | AAPL   | 2/1/2019  | 2.3    |
    | F      | 9/10/2019 | 4.3912 |
    | F      | 4/5/2019  | 3.6599 |
    | F      | 9/10/2019 | 3.5299 |
    | F      | 9/9/2019  | 2.7766 |
    | F      | 9/8/2019  | 2.6845 |
    | F      | 2/2/2019  | 2.6501 |
    | F      | 2/1/2019  | 2.3    |
    +--------+-----------+--------+
```

Output

```
    +--------+------------+-----------+--------+
    | Symbol | Start Date | End Date  | Delta  |
    +--------+------------+-----------+--------+
    | AAPL   | 2/1/2019   | 2/2/2019  | 15.22% |
    | AAPL   | 2/2/2019   | 2/3/2019  | 38.10% |
    | AAPL   | 9/8/2019   | 9/9/2019  | 3.43%  |
    | AAPL   | 9/9/2019   | 9/10/2019 | 58.15% |
    | F      | 2/1/2019   | 2/2/2019  | 15.22% |
    | F      | 2/2/2019   | 2/3/2019  | 38.10% |
    | F      | 9/8/2019   | 9/9/2019  | 3.43%  |
    | F      | 9/9/2019   | 9/10/2019 | 58.15% |
    +--------+------------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far and the challenge?

Comment: Why your sample data has two `9/10/2019` for `AAPL`?